# Как подключить скрипт?

Tags: ajax, javascript, json

В `JSON` ответе вырезается тег `<script>`, а мне нужно подключение js для дальнейшей работы страницы. Как подключить скрипт? 
Вот часть ответа:

```
<\/div> <!-- end .slide -->\n\t\t\t<\/div> <!-- end .container -->\n\t\n\t<div id=\"slider-left-overlay\"><\/div>\n\t<div id=\"slider-right-overlay\"><\/div>\n    \n    <script src=\"http:\/\/st.leu.su\/js\/superfish.js\" type=\"text\/javascript\"><\/script>\n
```

в нём присутствует js? но в исходном коде его нет. Следовательно он не выполняется.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Опишите, какой именно JSON-код вы получаете, что вы с ним делаете, и что хотите получить.

Comment: В вашем примере ничего не потерялось. Тег `<script>` внутри пустой - он подгружает исходник скрипта со ссылки, указанной в атрибуте `src=`: `http://st.leu.su/js/superfish.js`. Почему он не срабатывает уже другой вопрос. Вы полученный html вставляете в DOM-дерево?

Comment: Да, в DOM-дерево.

Comment: Он оказывается срабатывает, но его нужно загружать, когда уже весь DOM подгружен. Как это сделать?

Comment: Всё, разобрался.